# How to keep only repetitions that meet certain row assumptions when the matrix is 3D in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have the following 3D array:

```
x = randn(31,6,1000);
```

What I would like to do is to keep only those n repetitions that meet the following conditions:

1. the rows from 1 to 12 for the first observation must be positive;
2. the rows from 1 to 12 for the second observation must be positive;
3. the rows from 1 to 12 for the sixth observation must be positive;

In coding terms:

```
% keep only the n repetitions out of 1000 that meet:

% 1. x(1:12, 1, :) > 0;
% 2. x(1:12, 2, :) > 0;
% 3. x(1:12, 6, :) > 0;
```

Can anyone help me?

PS: The dataset is not representative of the original one, it was made just to see how a code would work.

Thanks!

Comment: Nitpick: A 2D array is called matrix. A 3D array is a 3D array, not a matrix. A 3D matrix is like a 2D vector.

Comment: The probability that 1000 random normal distributed values are non-negativ is nearly 0. It's around 1/2^1000. The probability that a column is non-negativ is 1/2^12 = 1/4096. The probability that 3 columns with 12 rows are non-negativ is 1/12288.

Comment: @ThomasSablik true! Yet, I just needed random data. I need to see the code to apply to my original dataset

Comment: Statistically you would have to call `x = randn(31,6,1000);` 12 times to get one result that fulfills the criteria. You can save a lot of time with `x = randn(31, 6, 3); x(1:12, [1 2 6], :) = abs(x(1:12, [1 2 6], :))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say that the random data is not representative, it most likely represents the results of some other calculations.

If you want to repeat these calculations, until the criteria are met, you can use a `while` loop:

```
n = 0; % some counter to keep track of the number of repetitions
condition_met = false; 
while ~condition_met && n < 100
    x = randn(31,6,1000); % where you get your x
    bool_arr = x(1:12, [1 2 6],:) > 0; % check if elements of interest are >0
    condition_met = all(bool_arr(:)); % and check if your conidition is met
    n = n + 1
end
```

Indeed with `randn` this is very unlikely to succeed, but you can check that it works by e.g. doing `x = randn(31,6,1000) + n` at the start of the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

The probability that

```
x = randn(31,6,1000);
```

creates data that fulfill the requirements is pretty low. Instead of creating random data and filtering it you could create required data:

```
x = randn(31, 6, 3);
x(1:12, [1 2 6], :) = abs(x(1:12, [1 2 6], :));
```

Alternatively you can filter with:

```
idx = logical(zeros(1, 1000));
for z = 1:1000
    if all(x(1:12, [1 2 6], z) > 0, 'all')
        idx(i) = true;
    end
end
result = x(:, :, idx);
```

An even shorter version is:

```
result = x(:, :, all(x(1:12, [1 2 6], :) > 0, [1 2]))
```

But as I said the probability is very low. I tried it instead with

```
result = x(:, :, all(x(1:12, [1 2 6], :) > -0.75, [1 2]))
```

and got no results in most cases and one result in some other cases.

`all(x(1:12, [1 2 6], :) > 0, [1 2])` checks the criteria and returns a logical vector. You can use a logical vector to splice an array in Matlab.

Comment: Very nice answers! Thanks a lot! I learned quite a bit from them.  As a personal policy, I tend to give the correct answer to the respondent with less reputation. But either answers worked well on my dataset